# cocos2d-x c++ -> java for android

Tags: cocos2d-x

Currently I'am developing a game using cocos2d-x.
Of course, for multi-platform use.
basically I use a xcode for coding and development. 
I want to attach IAP(In app purchases) separately to each coding for iPhone and Android
Problem to try to call a function of a certain class in Android that did not work.

Sources include the following:

cpp side

```
MyClass::invoke_init()
{
   JavaVM* jvm = JniHelper::getJavaVM();
   JNIEnv* env;

   jvm->GetEnv((void **) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_2);

   jclass cls;
   jmethodID method;

   cls = env->FindClass("com/joycestudios/game/SampleActivity");
   method = env->GetMethodID(cls, "initFunc", "()V");
   env->CallVoidMethod(cls, method); 
}
```

java side

```
public class SampleActivity extends Cocos2dxActivity
{
    public void initFunc()
    {
        Log.v("LOG_INFO", "initFunc()");
    }
}
```

The first test as follows: I'm in progress.
build from xcode and build from build_natvie.sh and last build from eclipse.
But after run on eclipse, Just black screen and shuts down.

How to call a function of a java class?
What I looked at several samples, including also analyze the problem, I do not see any problems?

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell if you find any error log?

First check if your game is working fine on android..

Den we can have a look how to call the function.

Generally for calling native method I use `MessageJni` class available in Cocos2d-x library.
I create my methods in `MessageJni` class which calls for native methods. 
Its easy and convenient way of calling native methods.

Just google using `MessageJni` class. It will ease your work.

:)